# How to successfully use Redisson Live Objects?

Tags: redisson

I'm having difficulty with two different parts of the Live Objects feature of Redisson:

1. Storing a nested `Map<String, String>` as a field of an '@REntity`
2. Using a condition to `find()` instances that I know are stored.

Here's my live object class (I'm using Lombok, hence the @Getter, etc annotations):

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor(access = PROTECTED)
@REntity(codec = StringCodec.class)
public class Manifest {

    @RId(generator = UUIDGenerator.class)
    @Getter
    private String id;

    @RIndex
    @Getter
    private String jobId;

    @RIndex
    @Getter
    private String rootFolder;

    @RCascade(ALL)  // Not sure this is needed, it doesn't seem to make any difference
    private Map<String, String> entries = new HashMap<>();


    public void add(String path, String hash) {
        entries.put(path, hash);
    }

    @Transient
    public int getSize() {
        return entries.size();
    }

}
```

I'm using this code to initially create and store the live object:

```java
    RLiveObjectService liveObjects = redisson.getLiveObjectService();
    var manifest = new Manifest(jobID, rootPath);
    manifest = liveObjects.persist(manifest);
    liveObjects.asLiveObject(manifest).expire(Duration.ofMinutes(60));
```

Elsewhere I use this code to get the object by ID and add data to its `entries` map:

```java
    Manifest manifest = liveObjects.get(Manifest.class, id);
    manifest.add(path, hash);
```

Somewhere else, I use this code to find the object:

```java
    public static Condition jobIDEquals(String jobID) {
        return Conditions.eq("jobId", jobID);
    }

    Collection<Manifest> manifests = liveObjects.find(Manifest.class, jobIDEquals(jobID));
```

With the code above, the two problems are:

1. The `manifests` collection is empty, even though I can inspect my Redis server (using RedisInsight) and see the hashes stored there with matching `jobId` values.
2. If I load one of the objects directly by its `id`, the `entries` Map is always empty, *even after* having added values to it. I see in RedisInsight that the value of `entries` is `org.redisson.RedissonReference@7623beea`, but there is no other key in Redis that corresponds to that reference.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

there might be some issues in your code that need attention. Let's address your two problems one by one:

The manifests collection is empty:

It's essential to make sure that your Redisson configuration is set up correctly to enable Live Objects. You should configure the Redisson client with the liveObjectService setting. Here's an example of how you can configure it:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.useSingleServer().setAddress("redis://localhost:6379");
config.setCodec(new JsonJacksonCodec()); // Use the appropriate codec for your objects

RLiveObjectService liveObjectService = Redisson.create(config).getLiveObjectService();
```

Make sure you have a valid config that connects to your Redis server.

The entries Map is always empty:

This issue might be related to the way you're updating the Manifest object and persisting it back to Redis. When you retrieve a Manifest object using liveObjects.get(Manifest.class, id), Redisson should load the object with its state from Redis. If the entries map is empty, it could be due to a few reasons:

a. Ensure that you've added values to the Manifest object's entries map before persisting it. You should call manifest.add(path, hash) before persisting the object using liveObjects.persist(manifest). If you add entries after persisting, the changes won't be reflected in the Redis-stored object.

b. Make sure that the Manifest class and its methods (e.g., add) are not being modified by any bytecode manipulation tool or aspects, as this can interfere with Redisson's Live Objects.

c. Verify that you're using the correct codec for your Manifest class. If you're using a custom codec, ensure that it correctly serializes and deserializes the Manifest object.

Additionally, you might want to check the Redisson documentation and release notes to ensure that you're using a compatible version with your Redis server and Java environment. Make sure you've imported the necessary Redisson dependencies as well.

If you continue to face issues, consider updating Redisson to the latest version, as there might be bug fixes or improvements in newer releases.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I'll answer in several comments. I'm on the latest Redisson version (3.24.3), and I'm using the redisson-spring-boot-starter dependency to get RedissonClient configured. I know it's talking to my Redis instance because I can see data in there created when I initially `persist()` the objects. My Redis version is 7.2, running in Docker.

Comment: I have configured the codec using both `@REntity(codec = StringCodec.class)` seen above as well as with a `RedissonAutoConfigurationCustomizer` that calls `config.setCodec(new StringCodec())`

Comment: When I initially create the `Manifest` I don't have any entries to add. It's another process(es) that retrieves the instance by ID and adds entries to it. That's the second block of code in the question. Do I need to `merge()` after adding entries?

Comment: I wonder if Lombok could be interfering, as it generates the getter and setter methods into bytecode of the classes. I'll try removing that to see what happens.

Comment: After adding entries to the Manifest object in another process, try logging the state of the Manifest object to verify that the entries are indeed being added correctly before persisting it back to Redis. and also check for any exceptions or error messages in the logs during the process of persisting and retrieving the Manifest object. This can provide valuable information about what might be going wrong.

Comment: Ensure that you are persisting the Manifest object back to Redis after adding entries. You can use liveObjects.persist(manifest) to ensure that the updates are stored in Redis.

Comment: Do all fields need getters _and_ setters?

Comment: In Redisson's Live Objects feature, not all fields need explicit getters and setters. However, the behavior of fields in Redisson Live Objects is influenced by the presence or absence of these methods

Comment: Still not working even after removing Lombok, adding getters/setters, and calling `merge()` after adding entries. Still `find()` isn't working and `entries` is always empty.